# Failed audit review on an opinion based question

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11868517

I flagged what seems to me to be a question that kind of borderlines between an opinion based question, and a request for a tutorial. Turns out it was a review audit and by flagging the question, I failed it.

Comment: Looks the correct action and a bad audit to me, so I've lifted your ban - however, you wouldn't have received a ban on a single failure. Please be careful moving forward.